# What are the differences between the MPI_* functions and PMPI_* functions?

Tags: mpi

I'm looking at the `mpi.h` header, and I'm confused about the `PMPI_Init` function. It's placed right after the `MPI_Init` declaration, and it looks exactly the same. However, `Msmpi.dll` (for instance) doesn't have the `MPI_Init` export, only the `PMPI_Init`.

What are these `PMPI_` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the MPI profiling interface. For each MPI function, there is also a similar PMPI function, which just differs by the prefix.

As a user, you should only call the `MPI` version and just ignore the `PMPI` version.

This is a mechanism that allows tool developers to intercept calls to the `MPI` functions and call the `PMPI` versions internally. Usually this is implemented such that all functions are implemented as `PMPI` functions and with `MPI` functions as weak symbols pointing to them. The tool can then replace the weak symbols with their own wrapper implementations and still call the `PMPI` functions internally.

```
// Normal case
user --calls--> libmpi:MPI_Init --redicrects to--> libmpi:PMPI_Init (implementation)

// Tool case
user --calls--> libtool:MPI_Init (does tool things) --calls--> libmpi:PMPI_Init (implementation)
```

You can find more information in Section 14.2 of the [MPI standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf). In general, I highly recommend to look in the standard for function signatures and such instead of the header.

Answer (score 3):

The `PMPI_` entry points are part of the [MPI Profiling Interface](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node182.html).

These symbols by default simply refer to their `MPI_` function namesakes, but by having them defined as part of the API, they make it easy for tools to insert themselves around MPI calls to do simple performance profiling or tracing.    There are [lots](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSF4ZA_9.1.4/pmpi_guide/using_profiling_interface.html) of [examples](http://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/mpi/class/advancedmpi/postscript/profilinginterface.ps) of how they work and how to use them.

[Most](http://ipm-hpc.sourceforge.net) [profiling](http://mpip.sourceforge.net) tools for MPI codes make use of this to do things like time MPI communication routines, count the number of messages being sent/received with particular sizes, etc., without having to modify the user code; you just have to link in the profiling library.

The Profiling interface doesn't have to be used strictly for profiling, of course - there have been projects that have used the profiling interface for communications correctness checking (making sure sends and receives were matched), simple heuristic deadlock testing, etc.

The profiling interface was the only standard tools interface to the MPI library for some time, but there is now also a richer [Tools interface](http://cscads.rice.edu/workshops/summer-2012/slides/performance-tools/2012-06-cscads-mpit.pdf).